# REGEX PARA OCULTAR CPF

Tags: c#, regex

Eu gostaria de uma regex para ocultar alguns números do CPF.

Por exemplo usar o cpf = "929.796.719-16" como entrada e ter o cpf "926.* .*.16" como saída.

Atualmente estou usando a função abaixo, mas não estou satisfeito com este loop na string.

```
public string FormatadoOculto()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        var chars = Formatado().ToCharArray();

        for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(i is >= 4 and <= 6 or > 7 and <= 10 ? '*' : chars[i]);
        }

        return sb.ToString();



  }
```

Comment: Regex por natureza não substitui ou inclui caracteres no texto de entrada. Pode fazer isso usando um método de utilização que usa Regex como "subject", mas com expressão regular pura não há como fazer isso.

Comment: Dá pra simplificar isso com `Substring` também: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SE3A2A

Comment: Inclusive, com `Substring` é bem mais simples que regex. E não medi, mas quase certeza que é mais rápido também

Answer (score -3):

Pode usar o seguinte regex:

```
([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{2})
```

e substituir por:

```
$1.*.*.*-$4
```

Com C# você pode utilizar o método `Regex.Replace()`:

```
var cpfOculto = Regex.Replace(cpf, "([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{2})", "$1.*.*.*-$4");
```